# two symmetric functions, when they have only one solution

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, contest-math

My Question:

> For what $y$ is the equation $\log_{y}{x}=y^x$, does there exist only one solution.

Some thoughts of mine:

What I noticed was that for almost any $a$, both functions $\log_{y}{x}$ and $y^x$ are symmetric with respect to $y=x$. Unsure how related this is though. But I suspect that it may help in some way or another.

Comment: You tag this as "contest-math." Which contest is it? Is that contest over?

Answer (score 0):

We can infer that since $\log_y x$ and $y^x$ are symmetric with respect to $y=x$, then if two functions have a single solution, then one of the two has to be tangent to $y=x$. Therefore, we are looking for the max of $y$ such that $y^x=y$ has at least one solution. For large $y$, the two curves will never intersect. Now what this means is the we are essentially looking for the maximum value for $y$ s.t. $y^{x}=x$.

Here is how you should proceed:

$$y^{x}=x \\ y=x^{\frac{1}{x}} \\y=e^{\frac{1}{x}\ln(x)} \\ \frac{dy}{dx}=e^{\frac{1}{x}\ln(x)}\left(\frac{1}{x} \cdot \frac{1}{x}+\frac{-1}{x^{2}} \cdot \ln(x)\right)$$

Now, in order to find the maximum value, we need

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=0 \implies \ln(x)=1\implies x=e$$

Therefore, $\displaystyle y=e^{\frac{1}{e}}$

Comment: Could you explain your first paragraph more? It is not obvious.